# Pass Variable to more than one page

Tags: php, html

I'm able to pass a variable from a link on my first page to the 2nd page, but i'm having a hard time passing that variable into the third page. How can i pass the variable to the third page?

**First Page is a HTML Page**

```
<a href="SecondPage.php?Page=Two">Go to Page Two</a>
```

**Second Page is a PHP Page**

```
<?php

echo $_GET["Page"];

?>
```

**Third Page is a PHP Page**

???

Comment: you can use session for this

Comment: Is there any other PHP behind the rendering of these pages? Or are you just using in-line php in HTML?

Comment: I tried using session, but i think session requires the first page to be a php file.

Comment: I'm using in-line php in HTML @Fyntasia

Comment: Then Sessions are the way to go!

Comment: then use extra link for third page also like
`<a href="ThirdPage.php?Page=Two">Go to Page Third</a>`

Comment: <a href="ThirdPage.php?Page=<?php echo $_GET["Page"]; ?>">Go to Page Three</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a variable along from one page to another you can choose from multiple options:

- Sessions
- Cookies
- Storage (File or Database)

#### Sessions

The first page:

```
<?php
// Prepare to use sessions (This should be at the top of your page)
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['test']) && isset($_GET['test'])) {
    $_SESSION['test'] = $_GET['test'];
    header("Location: secondpage.php");
    exit;
}
```

The second page:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Output session
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
```

#### Cookies

First page:

```
 <?php
if (isset($_GET['test'])) {
    setcookie('test', $_GET['test'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
```

Second page:
    ";
        echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['test'];
    }

#### Files and Databases

This is too big a subject to discuss in one answer. However, there are tons of tutiroals that can learn you all you need to know about PHP and MySQL.

#### Example

First page:

```
<a href="page_two.php?page=two">Go</a>
```

Second page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $_SESSION['page'] = $_GET['page'];
}
header("Location: page_three.php");
exit;
?>
```

Third page:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Will echo two
echo $_SESSION['page'];
?>
```

#### Resources

- [PHP - Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)
- [PHP - Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: The first page is a HTML page. The Second and Third pages are PHP pages.

Comment: The principal stays the same. You can POST/GET from HTML to PHP, Store the POST/GET data and then continue to use it in any page you wish.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but when i go to the 2nd page it says Undefined index: test file.php NULL

Comment: Can i use the session variable with the link i have in the first form?

Comment: I added an example to show you how to use sessions in your case.

Comment: It works, thank you! Question: In the second page section why write `header("Location: page_three.php");   exit;` ?

Comment: In case you want to go to a third page.. If you are staying in the second page this isn't necassery.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you for explaining it to me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options:

1. you can keep linking the pages with url parameters
   `<a href="SecondPage.php?Page=Two">Go to Page Two</a>
   <a href="ThirdPage.php?Page=<?php echo $_GET["Page"] ?>">Go to Page Three</a>`

This solutions is quite inconvenient if you want to keep the "page" value for a long term

2. The best solution as user1234 said is to store the value in the session.

if your first page MUST be html and you can't store it at begining you can do in any of your php pages

```
$_SESSION['Page'] = $_GET["Page"];
```